# PyMongo with Python2.7

Tags: python, pymongo

I am not able to use PyMongo with Python2.7. The following statements are not getting imported:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
```

error

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

When I try to use flask, it says:

```
Requirements already satisfied....
```

However when I use Python3 it works successfully. I have a dependency on Python2.7, I can't use Python3.

Comment: simply run pip as module in explicitly selected interpreter, do not use an endpoint:  `python -m pip install flask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have installed flask for python 3 but not for python 2.7 I assume that you might have used `pip3` for installing flask if that is the case `pip3` installs for  python3 and `pip` installs for python 2.7 by default. So check where flask has been installed if it is installed on python 3 it should be under **/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages** if installed on python 2.7 it should be under **/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages**. There may be additional lib paths where packages will also be searched. To see where python looks for packages

```
import sys
print sys.path#this will give you list of path where python searches for libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

As "Mani" answered, you have installed flask for one of your Python environments but not the one that runs your app. To avoid this confusion, never do this:

```
pip install "package"
```

Always do this:

```
python -m pip install "package"
```

Comment: What does `-m` mean/do?

Comment: "python -m" runs a module, in this case "pip", as the main function.

Comment: This runs the `pip` that is found by the current version of `python`, which should be whatever is in the virtual environment you activated.